# Any square matrix can be row operated into Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am doing a proof for a quesition, which requires an assumption that any square matrix can be transformed in to Triangular matrix using row operation

How do I  go about proving such obvious statement? 
All I can think of is the fact that any real number $X$ can be represented in multiple of any other real number, hence $X -my = 0$ .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, it's pretty obvious, so here is a brief answer which you can expand to whatever degree of detail you find necessary.

If the first column is all zero, then in particular the entries in rows $2$ to $n$ are all zero.

If the first column is not all zero, then swap rows (if necessary) so the the top entry is not zero.  Then use row-subtractions to make all subsequent entries in the first column zero.

At this stage you have reduced to a matrix in which the first column has zero elements below the diagonal.  Now use induction.